# Everytime when the rows in table are deleted, The Auto_increment will be reset to 1 at the next insert

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I'm working on MySql 5.6.19-log, Windows 7 Ultimate, X64. This thing confused me a long time, here is the thing:

I always set an Auto_Increment for primary key like 100001 when a table created, and it works fine when I insert some rows, delete something....., but if I deleted all of the rows, Then next time when I'm going to insert into this table, the Auto_Increment will reset to 1.

I don't know why, searching a lot and got nothing useful.

Hope someone can help me out!!! THANKS!!!

Comment: I believe it is because though the AI is set, the max has not been established, so it goes in as 1

Comment: This is a strange behavior. usually, the auto-increment counters are never reset automatically, you have to do it yourself. Do you have a trigger on your table?

Comment: Check: [InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT Counter Initialization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-initialization).

Comment: To Guillaume F: I'm sure there are not any triggers on it or pointer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `alter table` after a truncate.

```
create table t123
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    colB varchar(40) not null
) AUTO_INCREMENT=10000;


insert t123(colB) values ('a'),('b');
select * from t123;
+-------+------+
| id    | colB |
+-------+------+
| 10000 | a    |
| 10001 | b    |
+-------+------+

truncate table t123;

insert t123(colB) values ('a'),('b');
select * from t123;
+----+------+
| id | colB |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
+----+------+

truncate table t123;
alter table t123 auto_increment=10000; -- fire this off

insert t123(colB) values ('a'),('b');
select * from t123;
+-------+------+
| id    | colB |
+-------+------+
| 10000 | a    |
| 10001 | b    |
+-------+------+
```

Mysql Manual Page on [Alter Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Thanks Drew, you are right! Now I know, the Auto_Increment stored in main memory which means everytime when you restart the mysql.exe service in consle or somewhere, MySql will reset all the empty table's AI to 1.